# If f: A $\rightarrow$ B, and f is onto and one-to-one, and we have functions g: B $\rightarrow$ A and h: B $\rightarrow$ A, show g=h.

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

The question highlights in addition that:

f $\circ$ g = f $\circ$ h = Id$_B$, and g$\circ$f = h $\circ$ f = Id$_A$

I understand that in order to prove g=h, you must show that

1. the codomain and domain are the same, and
2. g(a) = h(a) for every a $\in$ B.

This one has stumped me. I've returned to it a few times, but I can never make sense of how to go about it. Logically, it makes sense, but that obviously isn't good enough in mathematics. So any input would be great!

Comment: The maps $g,h$ are from $B$ to $A$, so you should write $g(a)=h(a)$ for every $a \in B$.

Comment: Requesting clarification, are "$f \circ g = f \circ h = Id_B$, and $g\circ f = h \circ f = Id_A$" given, so you may consider the function $h\circ f\circ g$?

Comment: And about the question, $f$ is bijective, so it has an inverse, say $f^{-1}$, now can you use the fact that composition of functions is always associative in this problem?

Comment: I believe you can use associativity. Also thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

We have to show inverse of f is unique.
Let, $g≠h$ Then, there exist $x\in B$ such that $g(x) ≠h(x) $.let, $g(x) =u$
and $h(x)=v$. Definitely, $u≠v$(By our assumption)

Since, $f\circ g=f\circ h$ $=Identity$
Then, $f(u)=f(v)=x$ it implies f is not one-one which contradicts the given condition.
Hence, $g=h$